# Always Show Navigation Bar Nougat / Disable Immersive Mode

Tags: applications, 7.1-nougat

On some apps, the navigation bar and status bar are automatically hidden, and you have to swipe up to see them. Is there a way to force the navigation bar to always be visible on Android Nougat, like on top of the app or next to it?

Edit: In other words, is there a way to disable the immersive mode on Android apps?

Comment: Do you want to disable the immersive mode of apps? Is the status bar also hidden in those apps?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Yes, that's what I meant to say, I want to disable the immersive mode. And yes, the status bar is also hidden in those apps with the navigation bar.

Answer (score -1):

To force immersive mode and to force non-immersive mode, you must be rooted with [Xposed framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) installed in it.
 To do the same use app Immersive forcer. 
[This](http://dl-count.xposed.info/modules/com.hamzah.immersiveforcer_v3_96f79b.apk) is a xposed module and will work only if used with Xposed framework.

Remember you are not forced to root and by Rooting your phone can be risky and dangerous for your device.

Also, Rooting voids your warranty.
**MAIN THING is there is no xposed framework (official) for nougat till now and installing unofficial version if available can brick (soft/hard) your phone.**

Comment: This is not working. Only to force immersive mode is possible with this module, but not to unforce it.