# How to always show the status bar?

Tags: applications, 9.0-pie

All is in the title: I want to always show the status bar, even in fullscreen mode (basically, I want a deactivation of the fullscreen mode). Ideally, I would like to display it in portrait mode when I am holding my phone in landscape mode.

The reason is because I have a notch and I do not like it visually, so I would like to use it as a permanent status bar.

I searched on the Internet, in the play store, but I found nothing so far.

For information, I am using the oneplus 6 with android 9.

I read this question: [Always Show Navigation Bar Nougat / Disable Immersive Mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181198/always-show-navigation-bar-nougat-disable-immersive-mode) but it is about an older version of android.

EDIT: the latest Android version (10) made it worse. Now this isn't even possible to keep the bar black.

Comment: https://9to5google.com/2018/03/07/how-to-simulate-display-cutout-notch-android-p-developer-preview-1-android-basics/ Is this settings helped you?

Comment: @RahulGopi This article explains how a developer can **simulate** a notch.

Comment: "I would like to display it in portrait mode when I am holding my phone in landscape mode." - that would require a *massive* rework of how the statusbar / notification panel works, since the panel will now have to come out from the side of the screen. As for disabling immersive mode permanently, I'm sure it can be achieved by moderately modifying Android source, but for a built ROM, if even Xposed can't get it done, then I guess there's no way out.

Comment: For information, there is no standard way to even keep the bar black on the current android version. For people like I who do not want to see the notch, the "Nacho Notch" is a good app!